# Inheriting an abstract class vs implementing an interface

Tags: java

In the Effective Java book it is written:

> Existing classes can be easily retrofitted to implement a new
>   interface. All you have to do is add the required methods if they
>   don’t yet exist and add an implements clause to the class declaration.
>   For example, many existing classes were retrofitted to implement the
>   Comparable interface when it was introduced into the platform.
>   Existing classes cannot, in general, be retrofitted to extend a new
>   abstract class. If you want to have two classes extend the same
>   **abstract class**, you have to place the **abstract class** high up in the
>   type hierarchy where it subclasses an ancestor of both classes.
>   Unfortunately, this causes great collateral damage to the type
>   hierarchy, forcing all descendants of the common ancestor to extend
>   the **new abstract class** whether or not it is appropriate for them to do
>   so.

I don't see a difference between an abstract class and an interface here. Just, we can replace the highlighted word `class` with `interface` and everything further is still true.

```
+--------------+
|Abstract Class|
+--------------+
   ^        ^ 
   |        |
+------+ +------+
|Class1| |Class2|
+------+ +------+


+--------------+
|   Interface  |
+--------------+
   ^        ^ 
   |        |
+------+ +------+
|Class1| |Class2|
+------+ +------+
```

What is a difference?

Comment: The Java docs explain as well, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: "***Existing*** classes cannot, in general, be retrofitted to extend a new abstract class.".  ***existing*** is a keyword here.

Comment: In general **there are no difference** except one - class can extend only **one** abstract class, but implement **multiple** interfaces.

Comment: Related: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/223424)

Comment: There are 3 key differences between abstract classes and interfaces:

 1. Abstract classes can have non-static fields whereas interfaces can only have 
static fields.
 2. Abstracts classes can have a combination of concrete and abstract methods unlike interfaces, which can only have abstract methods.
 3. A class can only extend or "subclass" one other class. On the other hand, a class can implement as many interfaces as the developer wants.

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes can have non-static variables.

Comment: True, but what does it have to do with OP's question?

Comment: @PM77-1 In the last sentence they ask what is the difference.

Answer (score -1):

There are some important differences between abstract class and interface. Some of them are listed below.

1. Abstract class can have implementation in it but interface can't.
2. In interface you can have only static final variable ( all the values declared in intrface is automatically constant and static I.e immutable variables ) but in abstract class you can have mutable  variables.
3. Abstract class can be extended and only one abstract class can use for this but you can implement multiple interface in a class.